# __init__ в наследовании классов Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, наследование

День добрый, искал похожие темы, но не нашел в них ответа на свой вопрос. Книга из которой пример (Эрик Метиз - Изучаем Python) внятного объяснения тоже нет, либо я не понимаю его.

Итак, классический пример: есть класс родитель и его метод:

```
class Car():
    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year

    def get_descriptive_name(self):
        long_name = (f"\nЭто ваша машина: {self.make} {self.model} {self.year}")
        return long_name.title()
```

И есть класс наследник:

```
class Electric_Car(Car):
    def __init__(self, make, model, year, price):
        self.price = price
        super().__init__(make, model, year)
        self.battery_size = 75

    def get_descriptive_name(self):
        super().get_descriptive_name()
        long_name = (f"\nЭто ваша машина: {self.make} {self.model} {self.year} {self.price}")
        return long_name.title()
```

Собственно вопросы:

1. Комментарий в книге к  строке def `__init__(self, make, model, year):` класса Electric_Car следующий - "Метод `__init__()` получает информацию, необходимую для создания экземпляра Car ."

   Мне он ни о чем не говорит, пытаясь изменить эти параметры я получаю ошибку. Но я могу добавить в конец списка новый параметр и прописать (например `self.price = price`) под этой строкой. Почему тогда первые 3 параметра нельзя изменить?
2. В строке `super().__init__(make, model, year)` я не могу не добавить ни изменить параметры, т.к будет ошибка. Так как это параметры класса родителя?
3. Если я изменю любой параметр строки `def __init__(self, make, model, year):` то в строке `super().__init__(make, model, year)` он будет подчеркнут красным, соответственно эти параметры связаны, зачем тогда дублирование строк?
4. Я захотел переопределить метод `def get_descriptive_name(self)`, добавлением в него строки `super().get_descriptive_name()` а так же параметра `self.price` в переменную, правильно ли это?

P.S Посоветуйте толковую книгу по Python где все более детально описывается.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1, 2:** Через `super().__init__(...)` вызывается `__init__` родительского класса, в него нужно передать именно те параметры, который для `__init__` родительского класса нужны. Можно, конечно, передать какие-то другие параметры, но работать не будет, или будет работать неправильно :)

> Но я могу добавить в конец списка новый параметр и прописать...

- не обязательно в конец, можно в середину или в начало, главное чтобы при создании объекта передавались правильные значения в правильные параметры. Никакого правила, которое запрещает добавлять свои параметры в любое место, нет (кроме правила, что именованные параметры должны идти после позицонных). Но обычно чтобы не запутаться, лучше добавлять в конец.

**3:** это не дублирование. `def __init__(...)` - это объявление метода, а `super().__init__(...)` - это вызов метода. Если метод не вызвать, то сам он не запустится. Если вызывать метода с другим количеством параметров, чем было объявлено, то в данном случае это будет ошибкой (могут быть конечно методы со значениями параметров по умолчанию и всякими `*args`, `**kwargs`, но в данном случае этого нет, поэтому количество параметров должно совпадать).

**4:** в данном случае переопределенный метод никак не использует значение, возвращаемое родительским методом, и родительский метод никак не меняет состояние объекта (или "внешнего мира"), поэтому (опять же, в данном случае) в вызове родительского метода нет особого смысла. В других случаях вызов родительского метода может быть необходим.

Comment: По поводу книги - книгу не могу посоветовать, не изучал Python по книгам.

Comment: если не секрет, то как?

Comment: @Дмитрий интернет

Comment: поражаюсь вашей способностью фильтровать информацию и выбирать хорошие источники (не сарказм)

Comment: Да просто не бывает плохих источников. Подойдет любой источник, главное чтобы он отвечал на мой вопрос или решал мою проблему. Жаль что только в программировании так)